# Loading jQuery in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement an owl-carousel in my Magento webshop. I've loaded the .js file and the stylesheet. Jquery is (I believe) loaded from the template. When I use to code to activate the carousel I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

I think it is caused by the fact that the owl carousel script is loaded before the jQuery.
I'm loading the .js file from local.xml, but I have no idea where the jQuery is loaded.

When I look in the head of the page I can see the jQuery is loaded from:

```
skin/frontend/theme/template/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```

Does anybody know in which file the script is called?
Or how I can make sure the jQuery is called before the .js?

Btw if I include the .js in head.phtml its still called before the jQuery

Comment: It might just be addJs by xml files ordered incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

Open the file `skin/frontend/theme/template/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and put this code at last

```
jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now use `jQuery` instead of conventional `$` sign in every place (In your carousel jquery code). This way you can avoid jquery conflict in Magento

Comment: I've follow your steps but it didn't work, I still get the same error.

Comment: put your carousel script here.  you said you add jquery from template. If yes, put that code too.